# How exactly do you give blender more RAM?

Tags: texturing

I have a character that has multiple 4K textures, when I finished her I realized that blender slowed down allot in the workspace, the editor itself, using blender itself became very laggy and saving takes 5 - 10 seconds. I did not think blender would have a problem with 4K textures, since it is also used for very high fidelity movie and game production.

I have tried about anything, using better hardware ( a RTX 3060 12GB VRAM ), limiting the textures to 128, closing all other programs, but nothing wants to work. It recently crossed my mind that I never gave blender more RAM. I honestly don't know how this works.

Does blender just take the RAM it needs automatically without me having to manually assign more? Do I have to manually assign more, and if yes, how?

How exactly do I give blender more RAM ? Or is there another way to make blender stop lagging so much with higher resolution textures?

Answer (score 3):

You could change the number of undo steps in the Preferences, depending on how much RAM you have, but that's about it.

You do not need to do anything about Blender and RAM. If you install more physical RAM to your computer, the OS will use it and dedicate it to Blender as needed. There is no need to "optimise" anything for Blender and it should just work on any new computer with up to date drivers. In fact, it would be better if you do not attempt to "optimise" anything unless you know exactly what you are doing, and even if you do, any possible "optimisations" are not going to change much and it is also possible to cause problems by changing OS RAM management or GPU driver settings while trying to optimise, so it is a good idea to just leave it alone - Blender will work just fine without any extra changes.